# Concatenate DataFrames in ROW

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I want to merge two dataframes in pandas one is 126720 rows and 3 columns. The other is 1280 rows and 3 columns. The columns name for both datadrame are same. I tried to merge them in rows but the result has 'NaN' in the values because the number of rows in two dataframes are not same. The way i want them to be merged is to be placed under each other. In this way there shouldn't be any 'NaN'. In other words i want to have a dataframe with 128000 rows and 3 columns.Can anyone point me in a direction how to do it?

Here is the code i tried and led me to 'NaN':

```
df = pd.read_csv('.csv')
df1 = pd.read_csv('.csv')
result = pd.concat([df1, df], ignore_index=True)
```

Now dataframe is 128000 rows and 4 columns. Here is the screenshot of part of 'df' and 'df1'. [image] [image]

**Hint: I have a large dataset so i can not screenshot the whole dataset!**

Showing smaller size of df1 and df (**Just an example**):

df:  col1 | col2  | col3

```
   11  |   13  |  15
   ------------------
   12  |   14  |  16
```

df1:  col1 | col2 |  col3

```
   1   |   3  |   6          
 --------------------                                
   2   |   4  |   7
 --------------------                        
   3   |   5  |   8
```

What i want after merging:

result:   col1 |  col2 |  col3

```
       1   |   3   |  6
      ------------------
       2   |   4   |  7
      ------------------
       3   |   5   |  8
      ------------------
       11  |   13  |  15
      ------------------
       12  |   14  |  16
```

**I think my problem is row indexing for both dataframe is same. That is why i am getting 'NaN' when i am merging them. So how can i change the index of row before merging?**

Comment: Maybe your column names are not the same as you've expected. You can print out `df.columns[0], df1.columns[0]` and see if they are the same.

Comment: Nope! They are same!

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? The code looks correct to me. Maybe you get somewhere else that is wrong with your code.

Comment: @Pisdom i modified my initial post in a smaller case to show what i want!!

Comment: Can you remove the screenshot and post a few rows of the csv content of both dataframes?

Comment: Still, I think the example you give will work with your code. You might test it with a new session;

Comment: @Parfait I attached screenshot of part of both dataframes.

Comment: So there are no headers?

Comment: There are! but it won't help for this problem! I assure you the headers for both are same!

Comment: Please, please post the csv content! No screenshots as we cannot copy/paste into our environment. I did slightly reproduce your issue if there are no headers.

Comment: @Parfait Well how can i post CSV content here!? As it is very difficult for me to type both of two CSV content here!

Comment: Open csv in a text editor (not Excel/Lotus/Libre/Numbers), then simply copy first few rows of comma-separated data and paste it into the body of your post then format with `{}` button. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34146679/python-pandas-csv-parsing)